# How to initialize MongoDB connection in a controller in a Zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, mongodb, controller

I tried to do something like this in my MongoController. However, it doesn't work.

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $m = new Mongo();
    $db = $m->test;
}
```

I tried the same two lines of code in my application/views/scripts/mongo/index.phtml and it does work. I can't figure out why this happens.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you getting an error? What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be more inclined to create your DB connection as a bootstrap resource. In your `Bootstrap.php` file...

```
protected function _initMongo() {
    // you may want to get config options from application.ini
    // via the getOptions() or getOption() methods

    $mongo = new Mongo();

    return $mongo;
}
```

Then access this in your controllers like so

```
public function indexAction() {
    /* @var $mongo Mongo */
    $mongo = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('mongo');
}
```